# Listview AutoReziseColumns not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

```
ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
Listview1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
```

I'm having an issue since both of these lines separately produce the same result, which is resizing both the ColumnContent and the HeaderSize simultaneously.

I've searched and come up with no answer for this, i only need to resize by the HeaderSize but with the above example it seems not to be working correctly... or am i missing something?

And i've tested with more than one listview control...

Edit: I'm using it like this:

```
  Private Sub UserListResize()
    If Me.UserList.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.UserList.Invoke(Sub() UserListResize())
    Else
        UserList.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm calling this when i'm finished with adding items on the listview.

Comment: can you show how you are using it in code?

Comment: They dont do the same thing, but it is hard to tell them apart unless the header text is really long or short.  it **wont** shrink the column widths to match the header text if the "column" text is longer and/or would get clipped.  You could always set the column width to what you want and then change the header style to NonClickable.  Also, it doesnt do anything until you have items added, then as soon as you add more, it may be off again, so you have to call the method again.

Comment: Well, i just found out, i've setted all columns prior to adding the items to width of "40" and now the "ColumnContent" resizes correctly (only the items) but the "HeaderSize" still resizes both... any hints why?

Comment: because the subitem/cell contents are almost always longer than the headers.  the header method only works to fix the column size for long header text ("Days Missed" where the content is "2", "12", "23").  it doesnt purposely clip contents  (it will clip headers, it wont clip cell content).  you could also try the -2 trick (set each column width to -2 in a loop), to see if that gets you something you want.

Comment: i'm saying "lol", why does -2 have to do with anything? I don't see any Documentation online about this...
well, it resizes the header without me having to use the HeaderSize property... good to know i guess. It solves my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width.aspx): `To autosize to the width of the column heading, set the Width property to -2.`

Comment: Thanks for that too, but i think it's kinda "hidden" since i searched there the autoresize property which i believed was the problem, thanks again for searching for me ;).
If you want to answer i'd be happy in accepting it, otherwise i just +1 your comment..

Comment: Reworked the comments into something a bit more cogent as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They dont do the exactly the same thing, but it is sometimes hard to tell them apart.

`HeaderSize` resizes each column to the greater of `HeaderText.Length` or `longest cell content`, thereby never clipping the header text.

`ColumnContent` resizes to longest cell content which **will** clip header text if the HeaderText is longer then the content.  Test this with a column containing 1 or 2 digits/characters, but a long header like "FooBar Counter of Foo".

Neither mode will clip column text though, which means when you are economic with header text, it can look like they do the same thing.   Other things to consider:

- The LV must have items in it for `ColumnContent` to be meaningful
- Inspite of `Auto` in the name, it is not a persistent setting - as soon as you add something else the layout may be incorrect, so you may have to reset it periodically.
- You can always lay them out how you want and set `AllowColumnResize` to False
- You set `AutoResizeColumn` on a per column basis (note it is singular)

Individual column widths can be "auto sized" using the `Width` Property and the Magic Numbers of -1 (set to content) or -2 (size to Header).  This allows you to only apply the AutoResize logic to only some columns or use a different setting depending on the column:

```
 For n As Integer = 0 To myLV.Columns.Count -1 Step 2    ' just do every other
     myLV.Columns.Width = -2        ' -2 =  size to column header text
                                    ' -1 = size to longest content
 Next n
```

One place this is very handy is when adding columns dynamically.  Rather than guessing at the TextExtent, you can set the new column's width to something at least somewhat applicable to start with, then change it the first time content is added. Reference: [MSDN ColumnHeader Width Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width.aspx).

Comment: What a weird setting!

Comment: Yes, but its a weird control though!