# Listview Column AutoResize by HeaderSize or ColumnContent

Tags: vb.net, listview, autoresize

I have a list view that I would like to auto resize by the column contents; however, sometimes the contents of the column is smaller than the header field, so it gets cut off.

Is there any way that I could have it resize by column contents, but always make it at least wide enough to show the full header.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this just came up the other day.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24106546/1070452

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a sub that will do what I wanted to accomplish. Basically you just pass in the name of the ListView that you want and it will resize all the columns to fit the column content, or fit the header size if the content is shorter than the header.

```
Friend Sub autoResizeColumnWidths(ByVal lvControlName As ListView)

    Dim minWidthArray(lvControlName.Columns.Count) As Integer

    For i = 0 To lvControlName.Columns.Count - 1

        'Resize to fit the header
        lvControlName.AutoResizeColumn(i, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

        'Store the minimum width required to display the header
        minWidthArray(i) = lvControlName.Columns(i).Width

        'Resize to fit contents
        lvControlName.AutoResizeColumn(i, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)


        'Check to see if the minumum width is met
        If lvControlName.Columns(i).Width < minWidthArray(i) Then
            lvControlName.AutoResizeColumn(i, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: that code does the exact same thing as `myLV.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)` which is to size it to the Greater of HeaderSize or ColumnContent. There is also no need for an array - a simple integer variable is all you need.

Comment: Wow, so it does. Thanks I could have sworn that I tried header size before and it ended up cutting off some of the content, but I just tried it and it works fine. thanks @Plutonix

Comment: it is confusing because the results depend on the layout and the data currently showing in the grid.  Content never gets clipped except by the size of the Listview as detailed in the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/24106546/1070452

Answer (score 0):

You can set the column width = -2 to resize to show the full header.

Comment: When I did that it made the width 100% of the control and only showed one column. I actually figured out another solution that I will be posting here in a minute.