# vb.net Loop through Controls on Form and if ListView Loop through Columns and Rows

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have 3 ListViews in a UserForm and also a few other items. Currently when I expand the UserForm, the ListViews and other items expand in relation to the increase in size of the UserForm.

What I'm after doing is also expanding the size of the Columns within the ListViews by cycling through all Controls on the UserForm and checking if it is a ListView, then cycling through all the columns and extending as required.

This is where I am currently at...

```
 For Each Ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf Ctrl Is ListView) Then
        ' This is where I'm not sure what to do!
        ' I want to loop through this Ctrl and view its columns
        End If
 Next
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: The next step would be to cast `Ctrl` to a `ListView` so you can access its properties. I think you can probably take it from there...

Comment: you may just need `myLV1.AutoResizeColumns(...)`  [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24106546/1070452)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I did try doing this... `For Each ListColumns As ListView In Ctrl
                    MsgBox(ListColumns)
                Next` But the Ctrl is underlined as it needs something more. I tried `Ctrl.Controls` but no luck. I must be missing something somewhere but I just can't get it!

Comment: @Plutonix The columns are a set size, not autosized, I don't want them to be autosized to fit the contents, just to match the resizing of the page

Comment: @RichardC: See my answer for the correct way to get `Ctrl` to look like (get casted as) a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Plutonix' suggestion of enabled auto-resizing columns doesn't work, then read on...

To access the control's properties, you'll need to cast it to `ListView` first (so far you've only checked to see if it *is* a `ListView`. Then, you can loop through the rows and columns:

```
 For Each Ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is ListView Then
            Dim currentListView As ListView = DirectCast(Ctrl, ListView)
            ' Loop over the rows (items) in the view
            For Each item As ListViewItem In currentListView.Items

            Next
        End If
 Next
```

You might also end up needing a recursive control search -- your current loop will only look for controls that are a direct child of `Me`.

Another idea: simply return controls of the correct type in the outer for-loop:

```
For Each listViewControl As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ListView)()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In listViewControl.Items

    Next
Next
```

Comment: That is absolutly spot on! Thank you so much, I've never seen the DirectCast function, shall take note of that one going forward. Now all perfect, thanks again