# How to remove blank space from ListView WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, slider, items

Hello I'm experiencing a weird "bug?" probably not a bug but something with the spaces between each element in the listView. Ok so here's the code that i use to create it and also a picture of what's actual problem :

```
    public void UpdateStatistics(int fHands, int pHands, int lHands, int wHands)
    {
        listStatistics.Clear();
        listStatistics.Visible = Properties.Settings.Default.Statistics;
        listStatistics.View = View.Details;
        listStatistics.GridLines = true;

        listStatistics.Columns.Add("Properties", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listStatistics.Columns.Add("Fold's", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listStatistics.Columns.Add("Played Hands", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listStatistics.Columns.Add("Lost Hands", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listStatistics.Columns.Add("Won Hands", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        var itemsToAdd = returnStatistics(fHands, pHands, lHands, wHands);
        listStatistics.Items.AddRange(new[] { itemsToAdd });
    }
    ListViewItem returnStatistics(int fHands, int pHands, int lHands, int wHands)
    {
        int[] retStat = { fHands, pHands, lHands, wHands };
        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Totals", 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < retStat.Length; j++)
        {
            int k = j;
            item1.SubItems.Add(retStat[k].ToString());
        }
        return item1;
    }
```

- Picture : http://prntscr.com/9rf8no I can basically just drag the slider so the options will show up but it's really not comfortable for the user. How can i make it by default look like this http://prntscr.com/9rfajz ?

Comment: The magic trick of -2 for the width only works when there is data in the control.  Set the width of the columns explicitly or use one of the AutoResize methods after there is data in it.  [See this for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24106546/1070452)

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont fully understand your answer, i set the autosize property to true but nothing changes i also took a look at the post you linked but i dont understand vb too.

Comment: All the auto resize stuff only works when applied while there is data in teh control.  It is not like a persistant-keep-it this way kind of thing.  Look at the loop in the link - after you have data in it, THEN go thru and set them all to -2 (or -1)

Comment: `listStatistics.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);` This did the job thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Upvote the linked answer if it helped

Comment: Already did, fast and correct response really glad that there are people like you haha.

Comment: You should vote the linked answer additional to the comment ;) it's not compulsory at all but it's reasonable :)